# Service Fabric Kestrel 3.1 Https certificate through load balanser

Tags: https, azure-service-fabric, kestrel-http-server, service-fabric-stateless

Using Fabric 2 stateless services with Kestrel 3.1

Have a problem exposing a HTTPS endpoint.  A primary certificate is defined on the cluster (Security section).  This certificate (primary) is accessible to the nodes (i.e. via X509Store find operations on the thumbprint or subject) automatically by Service Fabric.  When configuring kestrel for a particular endpoint the certificate is used by the *UseHttps* method on any Ipv6 address (i.e. *Ipv6Any*).  In the Application Manifest the access to the certificate's private key is granted (see [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources)) with an endpoint policy.  Here is example code on [gist](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/b64fbc10becd87bb35c1dc81c2c0c96b).  The cluster's load balanser exposes the 443 HTTPS endpoint via the 8443 port (similar to the setup in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint)).

Despite the above configuration when navigating to the application the response is that the web page is either down or has been moved plus a **ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY** error.

The service according to the logging sent to Insights starts fine using the primary certificate:

```
Hosting environment: Production
...
Now listening on: https://[::]:443
```

Anybody else get as similar setup working?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had set the protocol to HTTP2 rather than HTTP1.